# Exception while generating dynamic query in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to write a dynamic query in Linq by importing Linq.Dynamic dll.
I want to compare date range in a dynamic query. But when I run the application I get an exception as per below.

Operator '>=' incompatible with operand types 'DateTime?' and 'Int32'

```
StartDate = Convert.ToDateTime("01-Jan-2016");
EndDate = Convert.ToDateTime("07-Jan-2016");

IList<TechnicianMasters> Technicians = ASM.TechninicianMasters.ToList();

string strWhere = string.Empty;
strWhere = "CreatedTime >= " + StartDate + " && " + "CreatedTime <= " + EndDate + "'";

supportIssue = ASM.SupportIssueDetails.Where(strWhere).ToList();
```

Here I am trying to filter data on the basis of CreatedTime in the range of StartDate and EndDate.

Any help will be appreciable.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Its converted to `string`. ie: `CreatedTime >= 01-01-2016`, since `1-1-2016 = -2016` it results in `CreatedTime >= -2016`.

Comment: To finalize what @Caramiriel was saying, just add single quotes around your variables (within the string), and you should be fine.

Comment: why do you not use the named LINQ query instead of the dynamic one? `ASM.SupportIssueDetails.Where(a=> a.CreatedTime >= StartDate && a.CreatedTime <= EndDate).ToList();`